# Какие существую javaFX дизайнеры для Eclipse или Windows?

Tags: java, javafx, design

1. Какие существую javaFX дизайнеры для Eclipse или Windows?
2. [JavaFX Scene Builder](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html) уже устарел и не поддерживается?
3. Нужны ли они вообще, gui-дизайнеры, или профи кодом пишут?

Comment: 1 - Scene Builder; 2 - качаем по этой ссылке:  https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/; 3 - по-разному бывает.

Comment: @insolor, вроде бы вы спрашивали на счет 2 пункта, вот с просторов интернета: "Приложение Scene Builder... Сейчас оно предоставляется Gluon, потому как Oracle теперь распространяет его только в виде исходного кода. Предыдущая версия Scene Builder 2.0."

Comment: Так в чем проблема? Не используйте то что предоставляет Oracle, а используйте версию от Gluon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scene Builder продолжает развиваться, правда, уже под крылом [Gluon](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/).

Из личного опыта могу сказать, что "дешевле" всё-таки в редакторе формочки создавать, хотя, если сравнивать, например, с редактором интерфейса для Delphi, то ещё есть куда развиваться.

Другой аргумент за Scene Builder - размер исходного кода. Если каждый элемент GUI создавать вручную - контоллер быстро превращается в груду плохо читаемого кода. Очень желательно максимально разделить представление и контроллер, чтобы они отвечали за свои непосредственные задачи.

Так же на будущее советую не пренебрегать и слоем сервисов, в которых реализовать всю бизнес логику. Контроллер при этом будет заниматься в основном обслуживанием интерфейса и вызовом сервисным методов.

То есть, в наших проектах я создаю FXML файлы и пишу под них контроллеры. К созданию элементов интерфейса вручную прибегаю только в случае необходимости.